# Cloudformation conditional statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I am trying to create a stack for ECS service with conditional statement for logging on ECS TaskDefination. I am trying to send the logs to different sources based on Environment but it is failing with below during stack update.

**Error**
*Resource handler returned message: "Model validation failed (#/ContainerDefinitions/0/Memory: expected type: Number, found: String #/ContainerDefinitions/0/Cpu: expected type: Number, found: String #/ContainerDefinitions/0/LogConfiguration: expected type: JSONObject, found: JSONArray #/ContainerDefinitions/0/PortMappings/0/ContainerPort: expected type: Number, found: String)"*

```
Conditions:
  HasDefaultLog:
    !Or [ !Equals [ !Ref EnvType, 'Prod' ], !Equals [ !Ref EnvType, 'Dev' ], !Equals [ !Ref EnvType, 'Sit' ] ]

ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Ref 'ServiceName'
          Cpu: !Ref 'ContainerCpu'
          Memory: !Ref 'ContainerMemory'
          Image: !Ref 'ImageUrl'
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: !Ref 'ContainerPort'
          LogConfiguration:
            -
              Fn::If:
                - HasDefaultLog
                -
                  LogDriver: !Ref LogDriver
                  Options:
                    syslog-address: !Ref LogDestination
                    tag:  !Ref ServiceName
                -
                  LogDriver: awsfirelens
                  Options:
                    Name: newlogdriver
```

The same works with below and able to see the logs in destination

```
LogConfiguration:
  LogDriver: !Ref LogDriver
  Options:
    syslog-address: !Ref LogDestination
    tag:  !Ref ServiceName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LogConfiguration` is object, not a list of objects. Sp you don't need `-` at the beginning:

```
          LogConfiguration:
              Fn::If:
                - HasDefaultLog
                -
                  LogDriver: !Ref LogDriver
                  Options:
                    syslog-address: !Ref LogDestination
                    tag:  !Ref ServiceName
                -
                  LogDriver: awsfirelens
                  Options:
                    Name: newlogdriver
```